# How to get Android app not to force close after returning from Google Maps Intent?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I'm calling an `Intent` to Google Maps from an item in a `ListView` in my app. After I'm done looking at the address in Google Maps, I press Back which pushes the Map from the address I sent in the Intent to user's current location then Back again to return to the app.

For some reason, my app force closes once I go back. <del>This ONLY happens when GPS is off.</del> Just to clarify, this is an Intent to Google Maps, not a MapView. <del>Oddly enough, LogCat isn't showing anything useful.</del>

Any ideas?

Edit:
LogCat shows these likely relevant messages:

```
W/PhoneWindow(26285): Previously focused view reported id 16908298 during save, but can't be found during restore.
W/dalvikvm(26285): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7e0)
```

Comment: You should check for null pointer and you can post part of your code.

Comment: "Oddly enough, LogCat isn't showing anything useful." -- look harder. There is *always* a stack trace associated with a "force close".

Comment: You're right. There were LogCat warnings, I guess I was looking only for Errors. Edited the original post with them. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Also just realized this DOES occur with GPS on. Don't know why it seemed otherwise.